# React Router with Meteor: How to remove code param from URL after redirect from OAuth without reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router

I'm. using React Router and React on a Meteor App.
I use OAuth and after the OAuth call to another site, that site redirects to my URL with the code.  e.g. http://localhost:3000/?code=lsK1o0FI8AV0WEVfxhEXiyjZL32we2&state=None

I then read code and use it in my application.  After getting the code though I would like to remove the code from the URL to hide it from the user.

How can I do that with React Router or Javascript without reloading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind history from react router. Then you need to extract param `code` from current pathname. If code exists you use the code and replace the url wich you need (for example `/`). This is possible implementation:

```js
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

const App = ({
  history,
}) => {
  const code = new URLSearchParams(
    new URL(history.pathname).search
  ).get('code')
  if(code) {
    useCode(code)
    history.replace('/')
  }
  return (
    <div>...</div>
  )
}

export default withRouter(App)
```